# Error install mysql server shared on GNU/Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

anyone know why i got this error...

and why i cannot install MySQl server on my VPS?

[image]

what i need to do?

i got this error :

```
warning: MySQL-shared-5.5.46-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5072e1f5
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-shared-5.5.46-1.el7.x86_64
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by MySQL-shared-5.5.46-1.el7.x86_64
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by MySQL-shared-5.5.46-1.el7.x86_64
```

=========================================================

i reinstall with mysql 5.5.45 and success install mysql-client and mysql-share..

```
[root@ryobest tampung]# rpm -qa | grep MySQL
MySQL-shared-5.5.45-1.linux2.6
MySQL-client-5.5.45-1.linux2.6
[root@ryobest tampung]# rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.5.45-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm
warning: MySQL-server-5.5.45-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5072e1f5
error: Failed dependencies:
        libaio.so.1()(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.45-1.linux2.6.x86_64
        libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.45-1.linux2.6.x86_64
        libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.45-1.linux2.6.x86_64
[root@ryobest tampung]#
[root@ryobest tampung]# rpm -ivh libaio1-0.3.109-44.3.x86_64.rpm
warning: libaio1-0.3.109-44.3.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 09ca02b0
error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1 is needed by libaio1-0.3.109-44.3.x86_64
[root@ryobest tampung]#
```

what must i do now? i cannot find rpm rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1

Comment: You have to install the required modules

Comment: what modules must i install?

Comment: GLIBC_2.14;FileDigests;PayloadIsXz

Comment: Why don´t use yum ("yum install MySQL-shared")? (Assuming it is RedHat/Fedora/CentOS.) Using rpm only, you will have to resolve dependencies manually.

Comment: i tried ..but i got "yum : command not found"

Comment: @Jens i already download GLIBC and tried to install it..then i got error "glibc is needed payloadlsxz" ... where can i download PayloadIsXz ?

Comment: well, any idea what Linux distribution is running on that VPS? This should probably be visible on the VPS´s webpage or documentation. It seems rpm executable is installed, but the distribution doesn't use rpms. You should use the distribution's native packaging system to avoid problems.
(For example apt-get for Ubuntu/Debian, zypper for OpenSUSE, emerge for gentoo...)

Comment: i cannot use apt-get ..i got "apt-get : command not found"

Comment: or must i install a newer version of mysql ? like 5.6 or 5.7?

Comment: I really recommend finding out which Linux distribution it is first, and posting that info here. The version will depend on the distribution. It seems you just downloader an .rpm file from EPEL repository, but that is only guaranteed to be compatible with RedHat or CentOS. 
Another thought: VPS may already provide a MySQL server configured and running, for example OpenShift does. So you would just connect to that MySQL server, no need to run your own.

Comment: VPS server using Centos-5-x86_64

Comment: @marek.jancuska i got a VPS without any services installed. may be thats why i cannot use yum and must install manually

Comment: If it is CentOS 5, you should use packages from CentOS 5. You were trying packages for RHEL 7 , as evidenced by "el7" in rpm file names, this is very probably another cause of missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing dependencies that are needed by MySQL server.

You have two way to go from here:

1. Install the dependencies one by one and then re try installation (longer way)
2. Install using the `yum` as shown below (faster and much simpler way)

   `yum install mysql mysql-server`

I would advice you to choose the later one if you do not have any issues with network access on your VPS, which normally not the case.

Comment: [root@ryobest tampung]# yum install mysql mysql-server
-bash: yum: command not found...
this is what i got..when im using yum

Comment: Please check if `yum` is not [installed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76432/bash-yum-command-not-found) on your server, then please install yum using `rpm`.